# execute custom function on database connection error

Tags: database, actions, wp-config

is it possible to execute a function on wordpress db connection error? I mean is there any hook or something in the (error stablishing database connection) thing...? I want to do something when I get to that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We you want to customise your Error Establishing Database Connection to something else then you need to create a file.

Here is the documentation for that

https://yoast.com/custom-wordpress-database-error-pages/